# Code not applying a timely sheet edit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs-api

I have code in a spreadsheet with a trigger to run it on form submit. The code is supposed to first create a link to allow for editing the submitted form data.  It has worked fine in older sheets, but in my latest iteration, it is not saving the link before proceeding.

This is the beginning of the code which is the function listed in the trigger:

```
function sendRegEmails(e) {

  var emailSubject = templateSheet.getRange("B3").getValue();
  var emailHTMLTemplate = templateSheet.getRange("B4").getValue();
  var emailWSAddInToHTMLTemplate = templateSheet.getRange("B9").getValue();
  var emailWSReqFormLinkHTMLTemplate = templateSheet.getRange("B10").getValue();

//Create and save the URL to allow the respondent to edit their registration
  assignEditUrls(REGISTRATION_FORM_ID, REGISTRATION_SHEETNAME, REGISTRATION_LINK_COL);
  Utilities.sleep(5000);// pause in the loop for 5000 milliseconds or 5 seconds to make sure the URL is in the worksheet

  // Create one JavaScript object per row of data.
  var objects = getRowsData(mainsheet);

  // For every row object, create a personalized email from a template and send
  // it to the appropriate person.
  for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; ++i) {...(continues)
```

This code is in a different .gs file in the same project:

```
/**-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
|    Begin section to create link to editable form
|
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

function assignEditUrls(PassedForm_ID, SheetName, urlCol) {
  var form = FormApp.openById(PassedForm_ID);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(REGISTRATION_SHEET).getSheetByName(SheetName);
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var responses = form.getResponses();
  var timestamps = [], urls = [], resultUrls = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
    timestamps.push(responses[i].getTimestamp().setMilliseconds(0));
    urls.push(responses[i].getEditResponseUrl());
  }
  for (var j = 1; j < data.length; j++) {

      resultUrls.push([data[j][0]?urls[timestamps.indexOf(data[j][0].setMilliseconds(0))]:'']);
    }
  sheet.getRange(2, urlCol + 1, resultUrls.length).setValues(resultUrls); 

}
```

When the email is sent the spreadsheet does not contain the URL. Has there been a change which would cause the assignEditURLs function to not save the URLs in the spreadsheet until after the other script is complete?  Has something been added that I need to include in the code to get this to be added?  I would like the email to go out within a couple minutes of the form submit.

As I said, this has worked in other spreadsheets. The only changes made to code has been to use the correct columns and files. The data ends up in the sheet, but not until after the email is sent.

- REGISTRATION_FORM_ID = the ID of the Form file
- REGISTRATION_SHEETNAME = the name of the sheet to receive the data
- REGISTRATION_LINK_COL = the column number in REGISTRATION_SHEETNAME to place the data
- REGISTRATION_SHEET = the ID of the Sheet file to receive the data

Regards,

Karl

Answer (score 0):

On some scripts I maintain I've noticed with the transition to new sheets, the sheet ID changes. If you haven't already, try updating the REGISTRATION_SHEET variable with the new id.

Comment: The variable does contain the new ID:1XlbmmlW8geV_zHvUJNs6Jsx-YCJ4EcBNBR6-Xnh8g0E  @CameronRoberts.  Other portions of the code work fine.  The assignEditURLs function is not always filling in the information prior to the calling function completing.  It seems to work sometimes, but no all times. In other sheets using the same code (with the constants correct for that file) it has had no problems.  I have not been bale to figure out when it does work but it appears to not work more often than it does.

Comment: It might, since it looks like you are opening the spreadsheet in multiple functions, placing flush() in the functions that execute before the problematic one, as well as in the one giving you trouble might fix the issue. However, I'm not totally sure, the ID issue was something I bumped into personally, but since you already had that taken care of I'm  just guessing along with you.